# Updating MKMapView while UITableView is scrolling, obtaining coordinates from cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit, scrollview

I have an UIViewController containing a MKMapView and an UITableView. Each cell in the tableView contains a set of coordinates. If you want to see, please check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77joV.jpg)

I want to the update MKMapView "in real time" as the tableview is scrolling with contains coordinates.

I don't need to use the didSelectRow method. Because user does not select yet.

What is the right code blocks for scrollViewWillBeginDragging method?

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrollViewWillBeginDragging")
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following as one possibility.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrollViewWillBeginDragging")
    for visibleIndexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
        print(visibleIndexPath)
        // 1. Get coordinates from indexPath
        //   e.g. restaurants[indexPath.row]
        // 2. Add annotation to a map view
    }
}
```